# NullPointerException thrown from ESIntegTestCase

Tags: elasticsearch, nullpointerexception, integration-testing

I am using Elasticsearch version 2.4.4.
Then I had created test case derived from ESIntegTestCase, something like:

```
public class ELSTest extends ESIntegTestCase {

    @Override
    protected Settings nodeSettings ( int nodeOrdinal ) {
        return Settings.builder().put( super.nodeSettings( nodeOrdinal ) )
            .put( super.nodeSettings( nodeOrdinal ) )
            .put( IndexMetaData.SETTING_NUMBER_OF_SHARDS, 1 )
            .put( IndexMetaData.SETTING_NUMBER_OF_REPLICAS, 1 )
            .put( Node.HTTP_ENABLED, true )
            .build();
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup () throws Exception {
        createIndex( "idx" ); // line 57
        ensureGreen( "idx" );
    }
}
```

After resolving "jar hell" problem and reading bunch of pages about *ESIntegTestCase* I got new one.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.elasticsearch.test.ESIntegTestCase.client(ESIntegTestCase.java:657)
at org.elasticsearch.test.ESIntegTestCase.client(ESIntegTestCase.java:650)
at org.elasticsearch.test.ESIntegTestCase.prepareCreate(ESIntegTestCase.java:763)
at com.company.ELSTest.setup(ELSTest.java:57)
```

What can be the reason for it? I mean the one where ESIntegTestCase class throws NPE in the line:

```
Client client = cluster().client();
```

It seems like cluster is not initialized. What is the proper very basic class setup, to start elasticsearch in tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself :-)

The documentation is located at: [integration tests](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/integration-tests.html)

There are the following extentions needed:

- Important limitation is that ESIntegTestCase class will work only with JUnit. There is no easy way to get it working with e.g. TestNG - explanation follows.
- Start JUnit with additional parameters:

  -Dtests.jarhell.check=false
  to avoid jar hell

  -Dtests.security.manager=false
  to avoid java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
- Class is declared as following:

  @RunWith( com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner.class )
  public class ELSTest  extends ESIntegTestCase {

  ```
  @Before
  public void setup () throws Exception {

      beforeClass(); // against NullPointerException in ESIntegTestCase

      createIndex( "idx" );
      ensureGreen( "idx" );

      // ...
  }
  ```

  }

*Remarks:*

- *@RunWith* is needed to avoid java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context information for thread: 
  and this is a reason why e.g. TestNG cannot be used - TestNG has no RunWith annotation.
- *@Before* cannot be changed to @BeforeClass as beforeClass() method cannot be called from static context.
- The method nodeSettings ( int nodeOrdinal ) is not mandatory.